# Flask server session loses data

Tags: python, flask, session, concurrency

I use the `flask-session` package to save multiple python objects during a session on the server. The objects are not JSON-serializable without a lot of additional effort, so using the filesystem store seemed like a good idea compared to client-side sessions.

Reworking the backend to not save as much data in a session is currently not feasible.

Please find below the flask code:

```
from flask_session import Session
from flask import Flask, session

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = "filesystem"
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "super secret key"
app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE'] = "None"
app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE'] = True
app.config['SESSION_PERMANENT'] = False

server_session = Session()
server_session.init_app(app)

@app.route('/write', methods=['POST'])
def write():
    key = request.form['key']

    # For simplicity. In the real application, this is a complex Python object instantiated by the backend
    value = request.form['value']

    session[key] = value
    print(session) # The key was successfully added
    return ""

@app.route('/read', methods=['POST'])
def read():
    print(session)
    key = request.form['key']

    value = session[key] # Key error
    print(value)

    return ""
```

Those endpoints are called via JavaScript `fetch´ methods, also concurrently. However, I can guarantee that there are no parallel writes to the same key in the session dict, and reading only ever happens after a write returned successfully.

I have multiple parallel requests to `/write`, but all posting a different key in the payload. During `/read` however, I get a key error on most keys. Sometimes 1 out of 10 keys is present, sometimes 2.

What can I do to keep a consistent session across multiple concurrent requests (if running the requests serially is not an option)?

Comment: You can store the `value` and `key` in some storage or any key-value pair database, then read it from there based on the key. or You can try to use a dictionary as a global variable, though it is recommended to use for large-scale projects, which can scale up using multiple servers

Comment: @shaikmoeed That is what I also tried and it works better than flask-session. However, handling cleanup is still an issue. I can handle `onunload` in the frontend to remove the dictionary entry to a specific session id, but this is far from reliable. From what I understand, flask-session actually does detect when a session finishes, but I couldn't find out how to replicate this behaviour.